# Boot fails(sometimes) after "Switched to clocksource tsc"

Tags: boot, 13.10

I am running on Ubuntu 13.10. I had worked on Ubuntu 12.04/12.10/13.04 and Linux Mint 13/14/15 both 32 and 64 bit versions.

I have faced with the same boot problem in all of these distros. After GRUB, **sometimes** it does not boot and I see a blinking cursor on the screen. It occurs at approximately %50 of tries.

I have tried to boot on recovery mode to see what happens. At the last versions, there are two lines which booting is stopped after:

> Switched to clocksource tsc

or(after this line)

> "New USB device found....
> Manufacturer: Generic
> SerialNumber 20100201....."

I have tried all the methods I can find for about one year but none of them worked. What do you suggest?

My computer: Lenovo Z580 Core i5 8GB RAM 500GB HDD Nvidia GT635M

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem on my Lenovo y480 laptop, running Ubuntu 13.10.

I read somewhere that this issue could have to do something with acpi. So I tried to boot using `acpi=noirq` as a boot option. (See [HowTo set Bootparameters](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/420))

This seemed to solve the problem, but being a Linux beginner, I am not sure at all of the implications of this option, so after a short time I went back to the 50/50 chance of a successful boot-up...